# Do contracted edges form a spanning tree of graph G? (doesn't have to be an MST)

Tags: graph, tree, cycle, shortest-path, minimum-spanning-tree

If you contract edges of a graph G until there is one vertex remaining, do the contracted edges form a spanning tree? If so, how do you prove this? I think you would end up contracting n-1 edges, so to prove it forms a spanning tree you would have to show that contractions don't form a cycle

**Doesn't have to be an MST!!